# Close a window (via it's window handle) without closing the process that owns it

Tags: windows, winapi, process, sendmessage

I'm trying to close individual windows from a processes whose code I do not have access to. The program spawns what look like internet explorer windows upon a button push, but they do not create an iexplorer.exe process (they all apparently live inside the application process). I've managed to get the process handle and the window handles for each "fake" IE window via some API calls, but I can't figure out how to close just a given window in a process.

I've tried

```
SendMessage(WindowHandles[i], 0x0010, 0, 0);
```

which is the WM_CLOSE message, but it closes all the windows in the process and ends the process. Is there a way to programmatically do something similar to what happens when I press the X at the top right corner of the window? The window isn't performing any computation or effecting any other memory spaces so I can end it however I want, but everything I've tried everything I know how to do (DestroyWindow; which returned error 5 permission denied, WM_CLOSE; which works but closes the process, WM_QUIT; which gives error 2 file not found and does nothing).

Any ideas?

Comment: WM_CLOSE is the right way to do this.

Comment: When you close the window using the X button, does the process end?

Answer (score 1):

You could send a SW_HIDE should technically work, although it wont close them, you can find more info at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Good suggestion, but does that mean the window is just taking up memory in the process somewhere? Not the most desirable solution, but I'll do it if I have to...

Comment: another way would be to simulate mouse clicks :) right on top of the X. Since you already have the handle WM_LBUTTONDOWN then WM_LBUTTONUP, probably not a good solution for production though.

Comment: haha well that's definitely something I thought about, but I figured I'd ask around before I start doing stuff like that!